# Different iphone model on same layout

Tags: ios, storyboard

I search what is the great way for creating a different view for any iPhone.
Example, I want to have a different view in portrait mode for iPhone 4s, 5/5s, 6/6s and another in landscape for 4s, 5/5s, 6/6s

I find the idea to create a different storyboard for 4s, 5/5s... But if i want to change anything, I must remember to change it on all storyboard! and this method create unnecessary Mb.

I'm in Xcode 7 and i want to use only storyboard interface because I beginning and I want to understanding how this work.

Comment: First, try to use auto layout to simply adapt to the screen size. If you want an entirely different layout then use size classes in a single storyboard

Comment: Auto Layout can come with size classes, but using with pure Interface Builder you cannot differentiate between the iPhone models you mentioned. I think for this you could use programatically setting specific contraints based on the current model or try first what Paulw suggests, designing an adapting storyboard..

Comment: start eg. here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started